# Mint - apt-get install -f wants to remove 447 packages

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I don't often have to mess with `-f` so I am a little bit at a loss as to why it is trying to remove so many packages, but I do believe allot of these packages I very much use, `apache2, aptitude, cinnamon` to mention just a few :O

Currently I am unable to install packages, hence the trying of `f`

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 google-cloud-sdk : Depends: python-crcmod but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: python-google-compute-engine but it is not going to be installed
 zoom : Depends: ibus
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

## Remove packages

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for hutber:  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils breeze-icon-theme cabextract chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra dbconfig-common
  dbconfig-mysql exo-utils fish fish-common git-man ipxe-qemu ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms kded5 kdenlive-data kinit kio
  liba52-0.7.4 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libaribb24-0 libavresample-ffmpeg2
  libbasicusageenvironment1 libcddb2 libdbusmenu-qt5-2 libdca0 libde265-0 libdirectfb-1.7-7 libdvbpsi10 libdvdcss2
  libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebml4v5 libebur128-1 libenca0 liberror-perl libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfaad2
  libfdk-aac1 libfdt1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libgksu2-0 libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgroupsock8
  libgtop-2.0-10 libibverbs1 libiptcdata0 libiscsi7 libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libjs-jquery
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libkate1 libkf5attica5 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5doctools5
  libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5
  libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifications-data libkf5notifications5
  libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5
  libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5
  libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5 libkwalletbackend5-5 liblensfun-data-v1 liblilv-0-0 liblivemedia62
  liblua5.2-0 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libmad0 libmatroska6v5 libmbedcrypto1 libmbedtls10 libmbedx509-0
  libmediainfo0v5 libmicrodns0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmlt-data libmms0 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2-4 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0
  libmplex2-2.1-0 libmspack0 libnfs11 libnl-route-3-200 libofa0 libopenmpt-modplug1 libpcre16-3 libpcre2-32-0 libpcre32-3
  libphonon4qt5-4 libplacebo4 libpng-dev libprotobuf-lite10 libpython3.7-minimal libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative
  libqt4-network libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5texttospeech5 libqt5webchannel5 libqtcore4 libqtdbus4
  libqtgui4 librados2 librbd1 librdmacm1 libresid-builder0c2a librtaudio6 libsdl-image1.2 libserd-0-0 libsidplay1v5
  libsidplay2 libsord-0-0 libsoundtouch1 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox3 libspandsp2 libsratom-0-0 libsrtp2-1
  libssh2-1 libssl-dev libtagc0 libtiffxx5 libtinyxml2-6 libunshield0 libupnp6 libusageenvironment3 libusbredirparser1
  libv4l2rds0 libva-wayland2 libvlc-bin libvlc-dev libvlc5 libvlccore9 libvo-aacenc0 libvorbisidec1 libvulkan1
  libwildmidi-config libwildmidi2 libxcb-xtest0 libxenstore3.0 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-common libxfce4util-common
  libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-2 libxnvctrl0 libzbar0 libzen0v5 lxmenu-data mediainfo openrazer-driver-dkms oxygen-icon-theme
  phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc php-cli-prompt php-composer-ca-bundle php-composer-semver php-composer-spdx-licenses
  php-phpseclib php-psr-log php-symfony-console php-symfony-debug php-symfony-filesystem php-symfony-finder
  php-symfony-polyfill-mbstring php-symfony-process php7.0-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline
  python-gobject python3-daemonize python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-netifaces python3-notify2 python3-pyudev
  python3.7-minimal qdbus qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 qtchooser
  qtcore4-l10n rawtherapee-data screen-resolution-extra seabios shtool smartmontools sox thunar-data unshield vlc-bin
  vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-video-output xautomation xfconf xfe-themes
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libutempter0 lynx lynx-common xterm
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-cyrillic
The following packages will be REMOVED
  adobe-flashplugin apache2 appstream aptitude apturl apturl-common audio-recorder avahi-utils baobab blueberry bluetooth
  bluez bluez-cups bluez-obexd bluez-tools bolt brltty caribou casper cheese cheese-common cifs-utils cinnamon
  cinnamon-common cinnamon-control-center cinnamon-control-center-dbg cinnamon-dbg cinnamon-desktop-data
  cinnamon-screensaver cinnamon-session cinnamon-settings-daemon cjs colord composer cups-browsed cups-pk-helper dconf-cli
  dnsmasq-base dnsutils dosfstools ecryptfs-utils evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common file-roller firefox
  flatpak fwupd gcr gdb gdebi gedit gedit-common geoclue-2.0 gimp gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-cinnamondesktop-3.0
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-flatpak-1.0 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-keybinder-3.0
  gir1.2-mate-desktop gir1.2-mate-panel gir1.2-matedesktop-2.0 gir1.2-matepanelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-meta-muffin-0.0
  gir1.2-nemo-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4
  gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gir1.2-xplayer-1.0
  gir1.2-xplayer-plparser-1.0 git gkbd-capplet gksu gmusicbrowser gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-calendar
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-keyring gnome-logs gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-themes-extra gnome-themes-standard gnome-video-effects google-chrome-stable
  gparted gsmartcontrol gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-vaapi
  gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf gtkhash gtkhash-common gucharmap gufw gvfs-backends handbrake
  hardinfo hexchat hplip insync-nemo ippusbxd iputils-ping iputils-tracepath irqbalance jsonlint kdenlive kerneloops
  keyutils libapache2-mod-php7.2 libappstream-glib8 libass5 libbabeltrace1 libblockdev-crypto2 libcacard0
  libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libcinnamon-desktop-dbg libcinnamon-desktop4
  libcjs-dbg libcjs0f libcolorhug2 libcscreensaver0 libcups2-dev libcupsimage2-dev libdazzle-1.0-0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2
  libdw1 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-19 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libecryptfs1 libedata-book-1.2-25
  libedata-cal-1.2-28 libedataserver-1.2-23 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libflatpak0 libfluidsynth1 libfm-extra4 libfm-gtk4
  libfm4 libfox-1.6-0 libfwupd2 libgcab-1.0-0 libgdata22 libgegl-0.3-0 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgimp2.0
  libglade2-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgoa-backend-1.0-1
  libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrilo-0.3-0 libgspell-1-1 libgssdp-1.0-3 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 libgtkspell0 libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgupnp-1.0-4 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgweather-3-15
  libgweather-common libgxps2 libhal1-flash libibus-1.0-5 libimobiledevice-utils libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
  libkeybinder-3.0-0 liblensfun1 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblzma-dev libmate-desktop-2-17
  libmate-panel-applet-4-1 libmateweather-common libmateweather1 libmenu-cache-bin libmenu-cache3 libmetacity1 libmlt++3
  libmlt6 libmovit8 libmuffin0 libmusicbrainz5-2 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libnautilus-extension1a libnet-libidn-perl libnice10
  libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libnotify-bin libostree-1-1 libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0v5 libpeas-1.0-python2loader
  libpoppler-glib8 libpq5 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libpython3.7-stdlib libqt4-opengl libqt5webkit5
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-calc libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-ogltrans librhythmbox-core10 libsnapd-glib1 libspeechd2 libspice-server1 libthunarx-2-0
  libtiff-dev libtiff5-dev libtimezonemap1 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity9 libunwind8 libvisio-0.1-1 libvolume-key1
  libwayland-egl1-mesa libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libxen-4.9
  libxplayer-plparser18 libxplayer0 libxreaderdocument3 libxreaderview3 libyelp0 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 lightdm ltrace
  lupin-casper lvm2 mate-desktop mate-desktop-common mate-panel mate-polkit melt metacity metacity-common
  mint-meta-cinnamon mint-meta-codecs mint-meta-core mintbackup mintdrivers mintinstall mintlocale mintmenu mintreport
  mintstick mintsystem mintupdate mintwelcome mousetweaks mozo mplayer muffin muffin-common muffin-dbg nautilus-data nemo
  nemo-data nemo-dbg nemo-emblems nemo-fileroller nemo-preview nemo-share net-tools netplan.io network-manager-gnome
  network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome nplan nvidia-prime-applet
  nvidia-settings obex-data-server obs-studio onboard openrazer-daemon openrazer-meta openssh-client orca packagekit-tools
  pavucontrol pcmanfm php-cli php-gettext php-json-schema php-pear php-xml php7.0-gd php7.2-cli php7.2-dev php7.2-xml
  phpmyadmin pinentry-gnome3 pinta pix pix-data pix-dbg pkg-config plymouth-label polo-file-manager polychromatic
  postgresql postgresql-10 postgresql-client-10 postgresql-contrib printer-driver-postscript-hp pritunl-client-electron
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python-appindicator python-apsw python-cairo python-dbus python-glade2 python-gtk2
  python-nemo python3-numpy python3-openrazer python3.7 qemu-block-extra qemu-kvm qemu-system-common qemu-system-x86
  qemu-utils qt5-style-plugins qwinff rawtherapee redshift redshift-gtk rhythmbox rhythmbox-data
  rhythmbox-plugin-tray-icon rhythmbox-plugins seahorse session-migration sessioninstaller simple-scan slack-desktop
  slick-greeter snapd sopcast-player speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng
  squashfs-tools ssh-askpass-gnome strace synaptic system-config-printer system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev system-tools-backends teamviewer thermald thunar
  thunar-archive-plugin thunar-gtkhash thunar-media-tags-plugin thunderbird-gnome-support timeshift tomboy
  transmission-gtk ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-system-adjustments v4l-utils v4l2loopback-utils vim-tiny virtualbox-6.0 vlc
  vlc-plugin-notify wget wmctrl xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-user-dirs-gtk xed xed-common xed-dbg xfe
  xplayer xplayer-common xplayer-dbg xplayer-plugins xreader xreader-dbg xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-input-wacom
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-qxl xviewer xviewer-dbg xviewer-plugins xwayland yelp zenity zoom
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libutempter0 lynx lynx-common xterm
0 to upgrade, 4 to newly install, 447 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,650 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,355 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I am running Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon, kernel: `4.18.0-18-generic`

Comment: Do you remember what led up to your inability to install packages?

Comment: The last `apt install` before i tried to use the fix in my history is `sudo apt install ibus` If that is a likely cause?

Comment: Ahh yes... i tried to install Zoom which needed ibus

Comment: If you do this, your Cinnamon DE will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Go into synaptic package manager, click edit, then select Fix Broken Packages. That should take care of the problem. If you can't run update manager after that, open a terminal and run the following command:  `dpkg --configure -a`. Please note, there are two dashes before configure.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `mint-meta-cinnamon` was removed. Now all other packages `mint-meta-cinnamon` depends on are no longer deemed "required", allowing apt to remove everything to "optimize" the system. Use `apt install mint-meta-cinnamon` to re-install the package.

Note: I am not absolutely sure you want `mint-meta-cinnamon`, but cinnamon is already installed. It is an educated guess.

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 zoom : Depends: ibus
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
`

So I need to remove zoom it seems

Comment: What happens if you ask for all mentioned packages explicitly with `apt install mint-meta-cinnamon ibus zoom`? I do not have a Mint installation at hand to try it, but on Ubuntu it works.

Comment: Thanks Herman, you lead me onto the trail of glory! :D I removed zoom and everything just worked again? No need to remove packages. I have no understanding of how this would be the causes of it